# I want to make middleware that doesn't work for some fields in Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I made some middleware in Laravel.. they work fine even with protected $except = ['password']; to ignore fields with the except array.

the problem is only with fields in livewire components, they work and don't ignore those fields.

I found this official \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class, middleware works fine with livewire components and ignores $except` fields as expected.

I have tried to copy TrimStrings class implementation to know what I have missed but unfortunately, the problem remains: $except` fields are not ignored.

this is my copy implementation for TrimStrings class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest;

class TrimStrings2 extends TransformsRequest
{

    protected $except = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    protected static $skipCallbacks = [];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach (static::$skipCallbacks as $callback) {
            if ($callback($request)) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->except, true) || !is_string($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        return preg_replace('~^[\s﻿]+|[\s﻿]+$~u', '', $value) ?? trim($value);
    }

    public static function skipWhen(Closure $callback)
    {
        static::$skipCallbacks[] = $callback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing this

```
if (in_array($key, $this->except, true) || !is_string($value)) {
```

To this

```
if (!in_array($key, $this->except, true) && is_string($value)) {
```

---

in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings2::class,
];
```

Comment: I get this error: Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [component-name] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.